# Priority Queue with Comparator returning different result

Tags: java, heap, comparator, priority-queue

The class is a FreqStack which two functions:

1. push(int x), which pushes an integer x onto the stack.
2. pop(), which removes and returns the most frequent element in the stack.
   If there is a tie for the most frequent element, the element closest to the top of the stack is removed and returned.

Here is my code for the same that I have written-

```
public class FreqStack {
    
    class CustComparator implements Comparator<Integer>{
        public int compare(Integer a, Integer b){
            //If the size of the list is bigger means higher frequency
            if(map.get(b).size() != map.get(a).size()){
                return map.get(b).size() - map.get(a).size();
            }
            //Lists with the same size means same frequency but the value inserted last should be at the top.
            else{
                List<Integer> listA = map.get(a);
                List<Integer> listB = map.get(b);
                int val = listB.get(listB.size() - 1) - listA.get(listA.size() - 1);
                return val;
            }
        }
    }
    
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map;
    Queue<Integer> q;
    int counter;

    public FreqStack() {
        this.map = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();
        this.q = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(new CustComparator());
        this.counter = 0;
    }
    
    public void push(int x) {
        if(map.containsKey(x)){
            List<Integer> list = map.get(x);
            list.add(counter);
            q.offer(q.poll()); //refresh the queue
        }
        else{
            List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            list.add(counter);
            map.put(x, list);
            q.offer(x);
        }
        
        counter++;
    }
    
    public int pop() {
        int key = q.peek();
        List<Integer> list = map.get(key);
        if(list.size() == 1){
            map.remove(key);
            q.poll();
        }
        else{
            list.remove(list.size() - 1);
            q.offer(q.poll());
        }
        return key;
    }
}
```

Here I'm doing the following push operations 30,40,4,25,20,40,48,21,12,44,1,16,20,9,34,26,12,21,35,16,3,23,9,31,10,6.

And the map after all the pushes looks like this -

```
{1=[10], 34=[14], 35=[18], 3=[20], 4=[2], 6=[25], 40=[1, 5], 9=[13, 22], 10=[24], 12=[8, 16], 44=[9], 48=[6], 16=[11, 19], 20=[4, 12], 21=[7, 17], 23=[21], 25=[3], 26=[15], 30=[0], 31=[23]}
```

Now I'm expecting my pop() to return 9 based on the Comparator I've written but it is returning 16.

> Can someone please help me understand why that is happening?

Comment: can you please add some comments to the code, it is really helpful to read the developers mind via comments rather giving a meaning to it

Comment: did you do a dry run on this. your comparator logic needs changes. write some test cases to check if your code is behaving as expected.

Comment: most likely the issue might be with the `Comparator`. note that the same `Comparator` is used in insertion as well. also, why do you expect `9`  what is your intuitive ?

Comment: @roottraveller because the last 9 was inserted after last 16

Comment: @LalitMehra I've added some comments. I've mentioned one test case at the end. I expect 9 as the result but I'm getting 16. I've tried debugging thought the PrioirtyQueue class without success.

Comment: @roottraveller. I've added some comments to the Comparator to make it a bit more clear. Since 9 was pushed after 16, i expect it to be popped first.

Comment: @noobMaster69 this "[16, 12, 40, 20, 6, 9, 35, 23, 10, 1, 44, 4, 21, 48, 26, 30, 3, 34, 31, 25]" is an internal display of the queue you have. check that 9 is way far from 16, 16 is the first element which is popped

Comment: Actually the same happens with 12 and 40 (if you don't insert this part: `[21],[35],[16],[3],[23],[9],[31],[10],[6]`). both lists have size=2 but even though 12 was inserted later, still 40 has a higher priority. The priority of 12 (also 9) is not refreshed somehow. You need to rethink the way of refreshing the queue.

Comment: there is no guarantee that the re-offered element (which is `q.poll()`) will have the element that you want to update (which is `x`), on its bubble-up path.

Comment: @mangusta That makes sense. The element not being on the bubble-up path. Thanks ! I will have to think of a different approach for the problem then.